# error MSB3073 when building Flutter desktop

Tags: windows, flutter, msbuild

Recently I just got the issue below when I tried to build a release version of a Flutter Windows Desktop application. I can run and build the project normally in debug mode. However, when it came to release mode, it failed. I am not an expert in windows apps, so I have no clue what's going on. Any suggestion?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows/x64
/Release/cargo/build/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/release/native.lib C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows/x64/Release/cargo/build/x86_64-pc-wi
ndows-msvc/release/native.dll.lib C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: setlocal [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows/x64
/Release/cargo/build/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/release/native.dll C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: setlocal [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\C
ommunity\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows/x64
/Release/cargo/build/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/release/native.pdb C:/Users/doan/Documents/workspace/workspace_proxy/proxy-application/build/windows [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\doan\Documents\workspace\workspace_proxy\proxy-application\build\windows\_cargo-build_native.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...
Build process failed.
```

Comment: The `_cargo-build_native.vcxproj` project has a Post-Build event which is shelling out and running a set of batch commands. The batch commands are failing and the shell is returning an error code of 1. See [MSB3073](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3073?view=vs-2022) for detail on the error code from MSBuild. When Visual Studio was installed, was the 'Desktop Development with C++' workload option included?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I did select it. It used to work before, but suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the machine? If yes, have you tried running a 'Repair' from the Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: did you maneged to make it work, i'm having the same issue, please let me know

Comment: I have similar issue did where you able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD with administration rights, then navigate to your project folder and  paste  `flutter build windows`. It's helped me once.

Short CMD example :

1. `cd myflutterproject`
2. `flutter build windows`

Another possible solution is open project in Visual Studio:

`YOUR_FLUTTER_PROJECT_FOLDER\build\windows\x64\PROJECT_NAME.sln` and try  build project

Answer (score 0):

`Max Ked`'s solution worked once for me and failed next!
I tried this and it works:

- Delete `.dart_tool` folder.
- run `flutter pub get --no-example`. Flutter extension should suggest you run this command by the extension itself after you delete the mentioned folder.